# Differentiation under the integral sign, please help

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

*Find the partial derivatives of the function:
$$\int_{x^2e^{5y}}^{\ln(x^3-2)}\cos(t^2)dt$$*

Maple responds: $$-2\,\cos \left( {x}^{4} \left( {{\rm e}^{5\,y}} \right) ^{2} \right) x
{{\rm e}^{5\,y}}+3\,{\frac {\cos \left(  \left( \ln  \left( {x}^{3}-2
 \right)  \right) ^{2} \right) {x}^{2}}{{x}^{3}-2}}.$$
What's the steps to solve this? I'm having trouble applying the FTC with two variables and partial derivatives...

Comment: Apply the FTC to each case independently

Answer (score 2):

The steps to differentiate under the integral sign are as follows;
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} &\left (\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(x,t)\,\mathrm{d}t \right)= \\
&\quad= f\big(x,b(x)\big)\cdot b'(x) - f\big(x,a(x)\big)\cdot a'(x) + \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f_x(x,t)\; \mathrm{d}t.
\end{align}
Basically, the limits are important as you must evaluate your function at these limits and evaluate a partial derviative in the last term, that's what the subsrcipt $x$ means.

For reference, see the [Leibniz Integral Rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeibnizIntegralRule.html) on Wolfram Mathworld.

Comment: Nice answer :) You might consider adding a link to [the Leibniz rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeibnizIntegralRule.html) for reference.

Comment: Consider it done :-)

Comment: So if my integral is only a function of $t$, the partial derivative in respect to $x$ of the function is: f(x,b(x))⋅b′(x)−f(x,a(x))⋅a′(x)? Does it change something if instead of a b(x) I have b(x,y)?

Comment: Here, you are differentiating w.r.t $x$ and so you treat $y$ constant. If you are implying that there would be a "higher dimensions" issue then you can differentiate under the integral sign in higher dimesions, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign_in_higher_dimensions#Higher_dimensions

Answer (score 0):

You can write $$f(x,y) = \int_0^{\ln(x^3 - 2)} \cos(t^2) \, dt - \int_0^{x^2 e^{5y}} \cos(t^2) \, dt.$$ Then use the fact that $$\frac{d}{dz} \int_0^{h(z)} \cos(t^2) \, dt = \cos(h(z))^2 h'(z)$$according to the fundamental theorem.